# React Router V5 HashRouter not storing history

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building a react app in which i am using react-router v4. I have my router defined properly like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import './styles/marmore.css';
import './styles/lasanha.css';
import './styles/stt.css';
import './styles/stt2.css';
import './styles/footer.min.css';
import './styles/header.min.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Store } from './store';

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={Store}>
      <HashRouter>
      <App />
      </HashRouter>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers:
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import EmptyCart from './components/emptycart';
import Cart from './components/cart';
import Identification from './components/identification';
import Cadastro from './components/cadastro';
import Entrega from './components/entrega';
import Pagamento from './components/pagamento';
import Boleto from './components/boleto';
import Imprimir from './components/imprimir';
import api from './services/api';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Route, Redirect, Switch, withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import { changeAuth, addRegister, addCart, addFinger, addStep} from './actions';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import $ from 'jquery';
import CryptoAES from 'crypto-js/aes';
import CryptoENC from 'crypto-js/enc-utf8';
import {mMobile} from './functions/index';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import Fingerprint2 from 'fingerprintjs2';

var blacklist = [];



const socket = io(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname, {path: '/events'});
class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {blocked: false, cartEmpty: true, out: false, mobileDevice: false, authenticated: false, cards: [], loading: true, loadingAuth: true, cart: { foto: '', vendedor: '', seller_label: '', nome: '', valor: '', valorAntigo: '', produto_id: '', presente: []}, user: { nome_completo: '', endereco: '', num: '', bairro: '', complemento: '', referencia: '', cidade: '', estado: '', cep: '' }}
    this.setAuth = this.setAuth.bind(this);
    window.onhashchange = () => {
      this.att();
     }
     window.onresize = () => {
      this.verifyDevice();
      }
  }
  
  verifyDevice(){
    if(window.innerWidth <= 481){
      this.setState({mobileDevice: true});
    }else{
      this.setState({mobileDevice: false});
    }
  }
  att(){
    let location = this.props.location.pathname;
    switch(location){
      case '/': // Sacola
        this.props.addStep(1);
        break;
      case '/identification' || '/cadastro': // Identificação
        this.props.addStep(2);
        break;
      case '/entrega': // Entrega
        this.props.addStep(3);
        break;
      case '/pagamento': // Pagamento
        this.props.addStep(4);
        break;
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.state.mobileDevice){
    
      mMobile();
  }
  }
  async componentDidMount(){
      this.att();
      this.verifyDevice();
      
      
      const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
      
      if(window.innerWidth <= 481){
        
        mMobile();
    }
  
    
    var fingerprint = await getFingerPrint();
    this.props.addFinger(fingerprint);
    
      this.setState({loading: true});
    var cartData = () => {
    if(getCookie('cart') !== undefined){
  
      api.get('/cart/data')
      .then((response) => {
      if(response.data.status == 'success'){
      var { foto, vendedor, seller_label, nome, valor, valorantigo, produto_id, quantidade, presente} = response.data;
      nome = decodeHtml(nome);
      this.props.addCart({foto, nome, vendedor, seller_label, valor, valorantigo, produto_id, quantidade, presente});
      this.setState({cartEmpty: false, cart: {foto, vendedor, seller_label, nome, valor, produto_id, quantidade, presente}});
      
      }else{
        this.setState({cartEmpty: true});
      }
      this.setState({loading: false});
    }).catch(() => {
      
        setTimeout(() => {
      cartData();
    }, 3000);
      
    
    });
  
 }else{
  this.setState({cartEmpty: true, loading: false});
}
    };
    cartData();
    this.setState({loadingAuth: true});
      if(getCookie('auth') !== undefined){
        var fingerprint = this.props.fingerprint;
        
        try{
          const { nome_completo, endereco, num, bairro, complemento, referencia, cidade, estado, cep, celular, email } = jwt.decode(getCookie('auth'));
          this.setState({authenticated: true, user: {nome_completo, endereco, num, bairro, complemento, referencia, cidade, estado, cep, celular, email}, loadingAuth: false});
          
        }catch(err){
        var userData = () => {
          api.get('/user/data')
        .then((response) => {
        if(response.data.auth == true){
          const { nome_completo, endereco, num, bairro, complemento, referencia, cidade, estado, cep, celular, email } = response.data.user_information;
          this.setState({authenticated: true, user: {nome_completo, endereco, num, bairro, complemento, referencia, cidade, estado, cep, celular, email}});
          var { cards } = response.data;
          if(cards != 'no_have'){
              //cards.forEach((el, index, arr) => {
              //  this.state.cards.push(arr[index]);
              //  if(index == cards.length - 1){
              //    this.setState({addedCard: true});
              //  }
              //});
            }
        }
        this.setState({loadingAuth: false});
      }).catch(() => {
      
          setTimeout(() => {
            userData();
      }, 3000);
        
      });
    }
    userData();
  }
      }else{
        this.setState({loadingAuth: false});
      }
  }
setAuth = async () => {
    this.setState({loadingAuth: true});
      if(getCookie('auth') !== undefined){
        var fingerprint = this.props.fingerprint;
        var getDadosA = () => {
        api.get('/user/data')
        .then((response) => {
        if(response.data.auth == true){
          const { nome_completo, endereco, num, bairro, complemento, referencia, cidade, estado, cep, celular, email } = response.data.user_information;
          this.setState({authenticated: true, user: {nome_completo, endereco, num, bairro, complemento, referencia, cidade, estado, cep, celular, email}});
        }
      }).catch(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          getDadosA();
    }, 3000);
      })
      }
      getDadosA();
      }
      this.setState({loadingAuth: false});
}
  render(){
    
    const {cartEmpty, loading, device} = this.state;
    if(this.state.blocked){
      return '';
    }
    
  return <div>
      <Header mobileDevice={this.state.mobileDevice} />
      <div class={this.state.mobileDevice == false && this.props.location.pathname == '/comprovante' ? null : "App clearfix"}>
      {loading ? ( <Loading /> ) : cartEmpty ? ( <EmptyCart />) :
        <div>
          <Switch>
          <div>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Cart trocarQuantidade={(quantidade) => { this.setState({cart: {...this.state.cart, quantidade}})}} deleteItem={() => this.setState({cartEmpty: true}, () => document.cookie = "cart=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/carrinho;")} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/identification" render={() => (this.state.loadingAuth ? (<Loading />) : ( this.state.authenticated ? ( <Redirect to="/entrega" /> ) : (<Identification device={this.state.device} setAuth={this.setAuth} />)))} />
      <Route path="/cadastro">
      {this.props.email.length > 0 ? (<Cadastro setAuth={this.setAuth} mobileDevice={this.state.mobileDevice} />) : (<Redirect to="/identification"></Redirect>)}
      </Route>
      <Route path="/entrega" render={() => (this.state.loadingAuth ? (<Loading />) : ( this.state.authenticated ? ( <Entrega mobileDevice={this.state.mobileDevice} {...this.state.cart} {...this.state.user} />) : (<Redirect to="/identification?from=entrega" />)))} />
      <Route path="/pagamento" render={() => (this.state.loadingAuth ? (<Loading />) : ( this.state.authenticated ? ( <Pagamento mobileDevice={this.state.mobileDevice} {...this.state.cart} cards={this.state.cards} {...this.state.user} removeCart={() => this.setState({cartEmpty: true}, () => document.cookie = "cart=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/carrinho;")} /> ) : (<Redirect to="/identification?from=pagamento" />)))} />
      <Route path="/comprovante" render={() => (this.state.loadingAuth ? (<Loading />) : ( this.state.authenticated ? ( <Boleto mobileDevice={this.state.mobileDevice} enterPage={() => this.setState({out: true})} {...this.state.cart} {...this.state.user} /> ) : (<Redirect to="/identification?from=comprovante" />)))} />
      <Route path="/imprimir" render={() => (this.state.loadingAuth ? (<Loading />) : ( this.state.authenticated ? ( <Imprimir mobileDevice={this.state.mobileDevice} enterPage={() => this.setState({out: true})} {...this.state.cart} {...this.state.user} /> ) : (<Redirect to="/identification?from=comprovante" />)))} />
      <Route path="*" render={() => (<Redirect to="/" />)} />
      </div>
      </Switch>
    
      </div>
    }
      
      </div>
      
     <Footer />
    </div>
}
}
 
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({ changeAuth, addRegister, addCart, addFinger, addStep }, dispatch);
const mapStateToProps = store => ({
  step: store.stepState.info,
  email: store.userState.email,
  authenticated: store.authState.authenticated,
  fingerprint: store.fingerState.fingerprint
});
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

Now when I go to signup page from the home and go to T&C page from the signup page now If I press the browser back button it is forwarding me to the Cart at / route. I am using react-router v5.2.0.

All is working fine till I don't use redux as I add redux in my project that breaks the browser back button.

Here are my Components

Identification.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, Redirect, withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { addStep, updateData, changeAuth} from '../actions';
import api from '../services/api';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import Fingerprint2 from '@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs'



var w;
class Identification extends Component {
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {loading: false, email: '', redirect: false, senhaError: false, firstStepRegisterSuccess: false, emailLoginError: false, emailLoginSuccess: false, loginError: false, showPassword: false, redirectTo: 'cadastro', senha: '', register: {email: ''}, firstStepRegisterError: false, registerErrorMessage: '', redirect: false}
      this.handleUserLogin = this.handleUserLogin.bind(this);
      this.handlePassLogin = this.handlePassLogin.bind(this);
      this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
      this.handleUserRegister = this.handleUserRegister.bind(this);
      this.handleVerifyEmail = this.handleVerifyEmail.bind(this);
      this.loginFacebook = this.loginFacebook.bind(this);
    }

    handleUserLogin = (e) => {
      this.setState({email: e.target.value});
    }

    handlePassLogin = (e) => {
      this.setState({senha: e.target.value});
    }

    
    handleUserRegister = (e) => {
      this.setState({register: {email: e.target.value}});
    }

    handleVerifyEmailInput = async (email) => {
      email = this.state.register.email;
      if(validateEmail(email) == false){
        this.setState({firstStepRegisterError: true, firstStepRegisterSuccess: false, registerErrorMessage: 'O e-mail não foi digitado corretamente.'});
      }else{
        this.setState({firstStepRegisterError: false, firstStepRegisterSuccess: true});
      }
    }

    handleVerifyEmail = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({loading: true});
      let email = this.state.register.email;
      if(validateEmail(email) == false){
        this.setState({firstStepRegisterError: true, firstStepRegisterSuccess: false, registerErrorMessage: 'O e-mail não foi digitado corretamente.'});
      }else{
        await api.get(`/verificar_email/${email}`).then(() => {
  
          this.props.updateData(email);
          this.setState({firstStepRegisterError: false, firstStepRegisterSuccess: true, redirect: true, redirectTo: 'cadastro'});
        
        }).catch(() => {
        
          this.setState({firstStepRegisterError: true, firstStepRegisterSuccess: false, registerErrorMessage: 'Já existe uma conta com esse e-mail.'});
        
        })


      }
      this.setState({loading: false});
    }

    
handleLogin = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({loading: true});
  let formError = false;
  let device, fingerprint;

  if(this.state.device) device = this.state.device;
  if(this.state.fingerprint) fingerprint = this.state.fingerprint;

  if(validateEmail(this.state.email) == false && validateCpf(this.state.email) == false){
    this.setState({emailLoginError: true, emailLoginSuccess: false});
    formError = true;
  }else{
    this.setState({emailLoginError: false, emailLoginSuccess: true});
  }

  if(this.state.senha.length <= 0){
    this.setState({senhaError: true});
    formError = true;
  }else{
    this.setState({senhaError: false});
  }

  const secret_key = 'SECRET';

  if(!this.state.fingerprint && !this.state.device){
    let options = {};

  await new Promise(resolve => { 
    Fingerprint2.get(options, function (components) {
     let values = components.map(function (component) { return component.value })

     device = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(components), secret_key).toString();
     fingerprint = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(Fingerprint2.x64hash128(values.join(''), 31), secret_key).toString();

    resolve();
  })
});


  this.setState({device, fingerprint});

}

  let {email, senha} = this.state;

  if(formError == false){
    await api.post('/login', {email, senha, device, fingerprint}).then(() => {
  
      this.props.setAuth();
      this.setState({redirect: true, redirectTo: 'entrega'});
    
    }).catch(() => {
    
      this.setState({loginError: true});
    
    })
  }
  this.setState({loading: false});
}

loginFacebook = () => {
  this.setState({loading: true});
  w = window.open(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/facebook.com','targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=620,height=545');
  let verifyClosed = setInterval(() => {
    if(w.closed){
      clearInterval(verifyClosed);
      this.setState({loading: false});
    }
  }, 1000);
  w.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
      let email = e.data;
      this.props.updateData(email);
      w.close();
      this.setState({firstStepRegisterError: false, loading: false, redirect: true, redirectTo: 'cadastro_cfb'});
  });

}

    render(){
        const firstStepRegisterError = this.state.firstStepRegisterError;
        const registerErrorMessage = this.state.registerErrorMessage;
        const loading = this.state.loading;
        
        if(this.state.redirect == true){
          if(this.state.redirectTo == 'cadastro'){
          return <Redirect to="/cadastro" />
          }else if(this.state.redirectTo == 'entrega'){
            return <Redirect to="/entrega" />
          }else if(this.state.redirectTo == 'pagamento'){
            return <Redirect to="/pagamento" />
          }else if(this.state.redirectTo == 'cadastro_cfb'){
            return <Redirect to="/cadastro?fb=true" />
          }
        }

        return <div className="Grid">
          {loading ? (  <div class="LoadingBackground">
          </path></svg>
  </div>) : null}
  <div className="LoginPage">
  <div className="LoginPage-title">Identificação</div>
  <div className="LoginPage-mainContainer">
    <div className="LoginPage-leftContainer">
      <div className="SignupBox">
        <div className="LoginBox-title">Quero criar uma conta</div>
        <form className="LoginBox-form" method="post">
          <div className="FormGroup">
            <label className="FormGroup-label" htmlFor="input-login-45495458">E-mail</label>
            <div className="FormGroup-inputGroup FormGroup-inputGroup--long">
              <input type="email" className={firstStepRegisterError ? ('FormGroup-input FormGroup-input--withError') : ('FormGroup-input')} onBlur={(e) => {if(e.target.value.length >= 1){ this.handleVerifyEmailInput(e.target.value) }}} onChange={(e) => { this.handleUserRegister(e); if(e.target.value.length <= 0){ this.setState({firstStepRegisterError: false, firstStepRegisterSuccess: false})}}} onFocus={() => this.setState({firstStepRegisterError: false, firstStepRegisterSuccess: false})} id="input-login-45495458" name="login" />
              {firstStepRegisterError ? <p class="FormGroup-errorMessage" id="aria-login-3cb8797a">{registerErrorMessage}</p> : null}
            </div>
            <div className="FormGroup-feedback">{this.state.firstStepRegisterSuccess ? <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="35pt" height="35pt" viewBox="0 0 35 35" className="Success"><path d="M14.523 29.73a4.129 4.129 0 01-2.93-1.214L1.34 18.262a4.14 4.14 0 010-5.856 4.145 4.145 0 015.86 0l7.323 7.32L27.816 6.5a4.145 4.145 0 015.86 0 4.145 4.145 0 010 5.86L17.453 28.515a4.136 4.136 0 01-2.93 1.214zm0 0" stroke="#fff" strokeMiterlimit={10} strokeWidth=".059" /></svg> : null}</div>
          </div>
          <button className="LoginBox-form-continue" onClick={this.handleVerifyEmail} data-ga="{&quot;category&quot;: &quot;Login&quot;, &quot;action&quot;: &quot;Criar cadastro&quot;, &quot;label&quot;: &quot;Selecionou&quot;}">
          <span className="mobile-hidden">Continuar</span> <span className="mobile-only">Criar minha conta</span>
          </button>
        </form>
        <div className="LoginBox-help mobile-hidden">
          Dúvidas? <a href="http://www.magazineluiza.com.br/central-de-atendimento/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-ga="{&quot;category&quot;: &quot;Login&quot;, &quot;action&quot;: &quot;Fale conosco&quot;, &quot;label&quot;: &quot;&quot;}">fale conosco</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="LoginPage-rightContainer">
      <div>
        {/* react-empty: 695 */}{/* react-empty: 696 */}{/* react-empty: 697 */}
        <div className="LoginBox">
          <div className="LoginBox-title">Já sou cliente</div>
          <form id="LoginBox-form" className="LoginBox-form" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
            <div className="FormGroup">
              <label className="FormGroup-label" htmlFor="input-login-2403024b">E-mail, CPF ou CNPJ</label>
              <div className="FormGroup-inputGroup FormGroup-inputGroup--long">
                <input onFocus={() => this.setState({emailLoginError: false, emailLoginSuccess: false})} onChange={this.handleUserLogin} onBlur={(e) => {let login = e.target.value; if(validateEmail(login) == false && validateCpf(login) == false){ this.setState({emailLoginError: true, emailLoginSuccess: false})}else{ this.setState({emailLoginError: false, emailLoginSuccess: true})}}} id="input-login-2403024b" className={this.state.emailLoginError ? ('FormGroup-input FormGroup-input--withError') : ("FormGroup-input")} placeholder autoComplete="username" name="login" />
                {this.state.emailLoginError ? (<div class="FormGroup-errorMessage">Insira um CPF, CNPJ ou E-mail válido.</div>) : null}
              </div>
              <div className="FormGroup-feedback">{this.state.emailLoginSuccess ? <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="35pt" height="35pt" viewBox="0 0 35 35" className="Success"><path d="M14.523 29.73a4.129 4.129 0 01-2.93-1.214L1.34 18.262a4.14 4.14 0 010-5.856 4.145 4.145 0 015.86 0l7.323 7.32L27.816 6.5a4.145 4.145 0 015.86 0 4.145 4.145 0 010 5.86L17.453 28.515a4.136 4.136 0 01-2.93 1.214zm0 0" stroke="#fff" strokeMiterlimit={10} strokeWidth=".059" /></svg> : null}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="FormGroup">
              <label className="FormGroup-label" htmlFor="input-password-da669599">Senha</label>
              <div className="LoginBox-input-password FormGroup-inputGroup LoginBox-input-password FormGroup-inputGroup--small">
                <input type={this.state.showPassword ? ("text") : ("password")}  id="input-password-da669599" onFocus={() => {this.setState({senhaError: false})}} onBlur={(e) => {if(e.target.value.length <= 0){ this.setState({senhaError: true})}else{ this.setState({senhaError: false})}}} onChange={this.handlePassLogin} className={this.state.senhaError ? ('FormGroup-input FormGroup-input--withError') : ('FormGroup-input')} name="password" />
                {this.state.senhaError ? (<div class="FormGroup-errorMessage">Insira a senha.</div>) : null}
              </div>
              <div className="FormGroup-children">
                <label className="LoginBox-form-label-show-password">
                  <input type="checkbox" className="mobile-hidden" defaultValue="on" onChange={(e) => {if(e.target.checked == true){this.setState({showPassword: true})}else{ this.setState({showPassword: false})}}}/><span className="mobile-hidden"> Ver senha </span>
                  <svg className="mobile-only" width={24} height={24} viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path fill="#8C8C8C" d="M12 5a11.83 11.83 0 00-11 7.5 11.82 11.82 0 0022 0A11.83 11.83 0 0012 5zm0 12.5a5 5 0 115-5 5 5 0 01-5 5zm0-8a3 3 0 103 3 3 3 0 00-3-3z" />
                  </svg>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            {this.state.loginError ? <div class="LoginBox-form-error--unique">Verifique o login e a senha para continuar.</div> : null}
            <button className="LoginBox-form-continue" onClick={this.handleLogin} data-ga="{&quot;category&quot;: &quot;Login&quot;, &quot;action&quot;: &quot;Continuar&quot;, &quot;label&quot;: &quot;Clique&quot;}">Continuar</button>
          </form>
          <div className="LoginBox-help">
            Esqueci meu <a href="#" data-ga="{&quot;category&quot;: &quot;Login&quot;, &quot;action&quot;: &quot;Esqueci email&quot;, &quot;label&quot;: &quot;Selecionou&quot;}">e-mail</a> ou a <a href="#" data-ga="{&quot;category&quot;: &quot;Login&quot;, &quot;action&quot;: &quot;Esqueci senha&quot;, &quot;label&quot;: &quot;Selecionou&quot;}">senha</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="Captcha">
          <div id="g-recaptcha">
            <div className="grecaptcha-badge" data-style="bottomright" style={{width: '256px', height: '60px', display: 'block', transition: 'right 0.3s ease 0s', position: 'fixed', bottom: '14px', right: '-186px', boxShadow: 'gray 0px 0px 5px', borderRadius: '2px', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
              <div className="grecaptcha-logo">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LduICwUAAAAAKAKuy-fjzvHxJFX9hs6MQHkuJGR&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9zYWNvbGEubWFnYXppbmVsdWl6YS5jb20uYnI6NDQz&hl=pt-BR&v=IU7gZ7o6RDdDE6U4Y1YJJWnN&size=invisible&cb=5pllwlbfztpc" width={256} height={60} role="presentation" name="a-rcyfduoztipf" frameBorder={0} scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" />
              </div>
              <div className="grecaptcha-error" />
              <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" className="g-recaptcha-response" style={{width: '250px', height: '40px', border: '1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193)', margin: '10px 25px', padding: '0px', resize: 'none', display: 'none'}} defaultValue={""} />
            </div>
            <iframe style={{display: 'none'}} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="GoogleOneTap" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="LoginPage-socialContainer">
    <div className="SocialLoginBox">
      <span className="SocialLoginBox--InformationLogin">Use sua rede social para se conectar*</span>
      <button className="SocialLogin-Facebook" aria-label="Fazer login com Facebook">
        <span>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width={20} height={20} viewBox="0 0 20 20" className="SocialLoginBox-button--FB">
            <g fill="none">
              <path fill="#FFF" d="M18.896 0h-17.8A1.104 1.104 0 000 1.104v17.8A1.104 1.104 0 001.104 20h9.58v-7.734h-2.6V9.238h2.6V7.01c0-2.582 1.578-3.99 3.882-3.99.778-.003 1.555.037 2.328.12v2.7h-1.588c-1.254 0-1.498.6-1.498 1.47v1.928H16.8l-.4 3.028h-2.6V20h5.096c.61 0 1.104-.494 1.104-1.104v-17.8A1.104 1.104 0 0018.896 0z" />
              <path fill="#4267B2" d="M13.847 20v-7.743h2.657l.408-3.032h-3.065v-1.93c0-.875.25-1.472 1.53-1.472H17V3.12A21.796 21.796 0 0014.622 3c-2.354 0-3.966 1.402-3.966 3.995v2.23H8v3.032h2.656V20h3.191z" />
            </g>
          </svg>
          <span className="SocialLoginBox-button--ButtonNameFB" onClick={this.loginFacebook}> Facebook </span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div className="GenericFooter">
      <div>
        {/* react-text: 751 */}*Seus dados serão preservados e nada será publicado em sua timeline. Serviço válido somente para pessoas fisicas.{/* /react-text */}
        <br />
        {/* react-text: 753 */}Em caso de dúvidas, acesse nossa central de atendimento.{/* /react-text */}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({ addStep, updateData, changeAuth }, dispatch);

export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Identification));
```

I deleted some functions because it reached the character limit. But they will not matter.. There are more components, but the architecture is the same, so I only posted one for you to have an idea.

Comment: I would advise that you look into how to use react-router, and also the way you are handling your routing stacked and all it makes it even harder for you to debug that cause the code is cramped and too much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router: Not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004926/react-router-not-working-for-me)

Comment: Why is it tight? In another project where I use react it works normal without redux.

Comment: I am to believe that redux has nothing to do with this bug but your code implementation of everything that in your **App.js** piece of advise **take it or leave it** in your app level try to keep as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
<Route path="*" render={() => (<Redirect to="/" />)} />
```

I removed it and it was resolved. But the question is: when a route is not found, I put it as the problem was in that part.